# Tuning Select statement to obtain faster results

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have benefited from this website for a long time now. This is my first question on the site. It is regarding performance tuning a reporting query. Here it goes.
1.

```
SELECT Count(b1.primkey) 
from tableA b1 --WITH (NOLOCK) 
join tableA b2 --WITH (NOLOCK) 
on b1.email = b2.email
and DateDiff(day, b2.BookedDate , b1.BookedDate) > 1
```

tableA has around 7 million rows. Email is a `varchar(100)` field. Bookeddate is a datetime field. primkey is a primary key column that is an int.

My purpose of writing this query is to find out the count entries that have same email ids but have come in one day late. This query take about 45 minutes to run. I really want to reduce the time it takes to execute.

Since this is for reporting, i tried in vain to use `--WITH (NOLOCK)` option to improve the read time. I have a column store index on tableA and I know that it is being used by the SQL optimizer - can see in the execution plan. I am using SQL Server 2012.

1. Can someone tell me in such a case, what would be better? Using a nonclustered index on email or a nonclustered columnstore index on tableA?

Please help me.

Comment: Please post the execution plan. If you can't yet upload an image here you can host it externally. Or upload the .sqlplan file somewhere.; How many distinct email addresses are there?; Consider this: if there are 10 records for a certain email at date 2013-01-01 and 10 records for the same email at date 2013-01-02 then this will count as 100 (not 10). Are you aware of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is relatively complex. You are essentially joining two tables that have 7 million records each on a column that is not unique.

How about the following query instead:

```
select Email
from TableA
group by Email
having MAX(BookedDate) > MIN(BookedDate) + 1
```

Also make sure you have an index with Email and BookedDate.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options here:

1. Create clustered index on `email` field at least for a larger table.
   But I suppose there are other queries running on these tables, and
   clustered index is needed on other fields
2. Move emails to another table, and store email id's in TableA and
   TableB; join on int field would be much faster than on varchar
   fields
3. Create indexes on email fields with included columns BookedDate (no
   need to include primkey, you can count on another field, or count(*). Code: `create index idx_email on TableA include(BoodedDate)`

I think that third option is the one you should go with. There's not much work to be done, and there will be great performance gain. The only problem is that index on varchar field will take a lot of space and impact insert/update operations; but you said that this is a reporting db, so I think you can allow that.

Comment: How could a 7 million row table lead to a running time of 45min? Even for heap tables that should be faster. There's something else going on that we don't know yet. SQL Server can even build temp indexes during query execution.

Comment: @usr Agreed, but the question is on tuning of a select statement, and we can answer that right away.